# pandas read_csv running continuously

Tags: python, csv, pandas, amazon-ec2

Ideally below lines should read 2 lines from file.
Code is working fine on my system but giving issue on amazon virtual machine.(process taking gbs of memory but not even completed running 2 lines)
I have python 64 bit installed on both system  & pandas is also present.
`import pandas as pd 
file1_read=pd.read_csv('D:\huge_csv\UBSRTOUBSR_ACCTPGP_first.csv',nrows=2,sep=',|\|',engine='python')`

Comment: It is most probably your `sep` kwag. What exactly is the separator like? Best to try without it...

Comment: I tried with removing sep argument so it will take comma as sep by default,still it is not working.I even tried remoing engine='python',but hard luck

Comment: Ah got it! It's your file name. `\ ` is treated as an escape character identifier. Change them to `/` and try. All Windows users at some point fall for this... And remove `sep` and `engine` kwags just to be sure.

Comment: I tried with r'' option & also with changing into directory & thenm running program but didn't helped...

Comment: After going through code i find that in parser.py of pandas pkg it is stuck at below line but unable to find reason behind it
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)